# Is it still possible to submit apps targeted for iOS5 or iOS6 to the App Store after the release of iOS7

Tags: ios5, ios6, app-store, ios7

Like the question says, will I be able to submit iOS5/iOS6 apps to the App Store given that iOS7 is rolled out now? Or do I have to target iOS7 for my builds?

I understand that there is a great amount of UI changes, new features, not looking good, etc involved but I just want to know if it is still possible to submit old targets

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is still possible to submit apps targeted at older versions, as long as they perform on iOS 7 as well.

There is also now an option for people using legacy versions of iOS to download app versions that are targeted for that version.

Nice article about that here: http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/09/17/apple-begins-allowing-users-running-legacy-ios-builds-to-download-older-versions-of-apps/

Comment: WARNING: that option is valid only for existing customers of your app, so they can redownload the latest version which is compatible to their iOS. If a new version of your app is iOS7 only, you will not be able to get new users/customers using iOS6.

Comment: Indeed. A valid warning

Answer (score 3):

Your app is *built* to a specific SDK version, which is different from the *deployment target*. Apple typically require you to submit apps that have been built to the latest public SDK version, although I believe right now you can still submit apps built to iOS 6.

So you can *target* iOS 5/6 as you require - however, going forward your app will have to be built with the iOS 7 SDK.