# iOS 7 no longer working with XCode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode4.6

I have XCode version 4.6.3 and have just recently upgraded the OS on my iPhone 4 to iOS 7. When I try to run my code on my device I get the following error:

> Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
>
> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to
>   run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

In `Organizer` I'm seeing the following message:

> The version of iOS on "My Phone's Name" is not supported by this
>   installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of
>   the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK;
>   which is available here.

The here link just prompts me to login to Member Center and doesn't drop me off anywhere about the latest SDK.

My deployment target is iOS 6.1, I don't want to raise that to 7.0 as the majority of our users are on pre iOS 7. I am running OS X version 10.8.3, can I upgrade my SDK? Do I have to? How can I make it so my SDK is compatible with iOS 7 and pre iOS 7 devices?

Comment: iOS7 requires xcode 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Developing with iOS7 requires that you upgrade to Xcode 5, which you can find free in the Mac App Store.

You'll still be able to keep your deployment target below 7.0 with Xcode 5.

If you don't have a dev iPhone with iOS 6.x you can go into Xcode > Preferences > Downloads to install the iOS6 simulator, command line tools, and any additional documentation.

**Update 1**

If you update your phone to iOS 7.1, you will also be required to update your version of Xcode to 5.1

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. I still have to wait 8 minutes before I can accept your answer.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that if you transition to iOS 7 sdk, you need to support the new UI changes. There's also a way to keep both of the Xcodes and build on a ios7 device with ios6 sdk...

Comment: Ok, if I don't upgrade my SDK can I submit a version of an existing app that doesn't natively support the UI changes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869644/is-it-still-possible-to-submit-apps-targeted-for-ios5-or-ios6-to-the-app-store-a this link might help with answering that

Comment: This is really annoying.  This morning, the iPad demanded that it needed to be updated to iOS 7, which I did.  And then XCode 4.6 wouldn't connect to it, as it demands a more up-to-date version.  But to install this update, it demands that you have upgraded to OS Maverick.  I also had to upgrade iTunes to the latest version.  Talk about holding a gun to the developer's head !!

Comment: You shouldn't have had to upgrade to Mavericks to get Xcode 5 as far as I know

Comment: Ya, its not necessary to upgrade mac os Mavericks for installing Xcode 5. I'm using mountain lion os with XCode 5.1 @MikeGledhill

Comment: Is it possible to compile an app with Xcode 4.6 / target SDK iOS 6 and then use adhoc-distribution to install the result on an iOS 7 device? Of course, there would be no "life" debugger connection in this case.

Answer (score 8):

My iPad mini running iOS 7.04 would occasionally stop working with Xcode 4.6.3 as well. I found that starting up my app in Xcode 5 then closing down and re-opening in Xcode 4 would consistently fix this. I am not sure exactly why that works, I can only speculate that it resets some flags somewhere. But this does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Its preferable to use Xcode 5 as its an update by apple, but compiling with xcode 5 make UI Changes to the application. So, for that case if you dont want to change, I have the solution following solution to run your app with xcode 4.6.3 on iphone 4 with ios 7 update.

I was also facing this same problem but able to get it resolved by quit Xcode and iphone simulator once and then restart my xcode 4.6.3 and then connecting my ios device, made this problem resolved and now able to run my application on iphone 4 with ios 7 via xcode 4.6.3.