# Test my iOS app in iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I developed a iOS app using XCode version 4.6.3 with deployment target version to 5.0.

I completed this app and tested in simulator, everything is fine.

Now, I connected my iPhone 5s to my mac system and selected iOS device to test instead of simulator.

I am not able to see this app in my iPhone and following alert shows while run the app,

```
Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.
```

Comment: For running iOS app in the real device, its need proper Provision for the app.In Simulator i will run with out any authentication. But in device need to create keychain and provisioning files.

Comment: What is your iphone 5s version?

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139215/ios-7-no-longer-working-with-xcode-4-6-3

Comment: You can find the answer in the below link. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x?lq=1>

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Xcode4.x , you have to create provisioning profile for your app in Apple Developer Center. Add your device in your developer account. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a problem with your version of Xcode/iOS/OS X, but rather that you have not provisioned your device. You need to add your provisioning profile to the device to allow you to test apps on it. Newer versions of Xcode will do this for you, but you can still do it with older versions yourself in the Member Center.

Answer (score 0):

If your iPhone version is above 7.1 You need to upgrade your xcode to support version higher than that. You can only test devices lower than 7.1 in xcode 4.6.3. I hope this will be helpful

Comment: my Mac version 10.7.5, is this possible to upgrade my XCode to latest version, I think this is very much older system with 2.5Ghz Intel corei5, Memory 4GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Comment: Im asking about your test device iPhone5s version?

Comment: Sorry, phone's version is 9.1.3

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161998/install-an-older-version-of-xcode-on-mac-lion-10-7 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5396437?tstart=0 follow this link for more info

Comment: If you wish to update you xcode you should Update your mac