# How to upload iOS 6 app which can run on iOS 7 with iOS legacy Look

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an app before release of iOS 7 and now i want to upload the next version of my app which can run on iOS7 but looks like iOS 7 UI.

Comment: There are several guides on the Internet on how to upgrade an iOS 6 to iOS 7. If that is what you are asking for. Reading the title and the actual question, it is hard to understand what you really is asking for.

Comment: Actually what happen when i am going to create a build using xcode 5.1 i am getting some error of valid architecture which is out of my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had same problem and by using this solution everything working fine. so try it out.

open Finder and find your Xcode 4.6.3 package
right-click and select “show package contents”
navigate to Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
you’ll find a folder called iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
copy it
Now that we’ve got it, let’s paste it into the very same directory in Xcode 5:

open Finder again and find your Xcode 5 package
right-click and select “show package contents”
navigate to Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
you’ll find a folder here called iPhoneOS7.0.sdk (that’s the “latest” at the time of writing)
paste the iPhoneOS6.1.sdk folder here   and set basesdk in xcode target setting to ios 6.1.

Comment: When was this, because Apple official states that app must be optimized for iOS 7. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a

Comment: Also this doesn't lead to having an iOS6 look on iOS7 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Please read question carefully first the question for before release of iOS7.

Comment: @Santosh even an update must optimized for iOS 7. Not just new apps.

Answer (score 3):

There are some issue here, you can not use the iOS 6 SDk to submit you update since Apple only allows submission of iOS 7 SDK build. Also you need to use at least Xcode 5.1 to submit.

So you will have to convert you app to use the iOS 7 SDK, which will make it look like iOS 7. You will then need to write you on appearance for the UI controls which you want to have in a iOS 6 look (this will be very difficult to do for all control especially `UIPickerViews`).

Just make you app look good under iOS 7 and use appearance proxy to make it look good in iOS 6 is probably easier.

Comment: I went through this link and according to it i it is possible           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869644/is-it-still-possible-to-submit-apps-targeted-for-ios5-or-ios6-to-the-app-store-a

Comment: The answer is to old, Apple released this statement: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a Here you can read that you need to submit you app with Xcode 5.1.1 and in this announcement you read that you app need to be optimized for iOS 7: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a.